# view history deleted after setting axis limits in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

after setting limits of matplotlib axes using set_xlim, the reset original view is not the first original any more. Is it possible to set programmatically the limits without deleting the view history?

mwe:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([0,1], [1,2])
plt.show(block=False)
ax.set_xlim(.5,1.)
plt.draw()
```

Pressing the reset orignal view button does not reset the view to xlim = (0,1), however the data is still in the figure. How to set the view via set_xlim or something similar, without deleting the view history?

Comment: The GUI keeps the stack of axes limits, so it doesn’t know anything about what you type in manually.  You can probably look at the source code and fake the GUI calls to put your changes in the stack rather than calling xlim, but it’d take a bit of research.